# interactive markers does not work with gmapping_demo

Tags: ros, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do SLAM to map my room with my turtlebot. Using Indigo on turtlebot and Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.04 on host PC. I can get the interactive markers to work and navigate the turtlebot just fine from the host PC following the tutorial here:
[interactive_markers](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_interactive_markers/Tutorials/indigo/UsingTurtlebotInteractiveMarkers)
When I try to run the mapping tutorial here:
[navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM)
The rviz comes up fine but without interactive markers as a selection. SO I tried running
ON host PC:

> roslaunch turtlebot_interactive_markers interactive_markers.launch --screen

and then I added the interactive markers using the add button from rviz, enabled it and tried clicking on the interactive button but nothing happens. The navigation by interactive markers does not  come up. What do I need to do differently to get interactive_marker navigation to work during mapping?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260899/interactive-markers-does-not-work-with-gmapping_demo/) by [mrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30238/mrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After comparing the configuration files in `/turtlebot_rviz_launchers/rviz`

> 

I found what seems to be a solution. When you run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
```

It uses a configuration file `navigation.rviz`, if you compare that to the file used by

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

which is `robot.rviz`, you see that `robot.rviz` has  lines in it to add the class `rviz/InteractiveMarkers`,
evidently you can not simply add interactive markers from rviz gui, it must be declared in the configuration file first. The file `navigation.rviz` did not have these lines so I added them:

```
- Class: rviz/InteractiveMarkers
  Enabled: false
  Name: InteractiveMarkers
  Show Axes: false
  Show Descriptions: true
  Show Visual Aids: false
  Update Topic: /turtlebot_marker_server/update
  Value: false
```

Once I did this and launched rviz again with above commands, the interactive marker was in rviz and when I clicked on the interactive button, I could navigate using interactive markers while mapping was taking place. Of course you still have to run

```
roslaunch turtlebot_interactive_markers interactive_markers.launch --screen
```

I do not really understand the syntax in the *.rviz files. I could attach my modified `navigation.rviz` so others can do a diff and see where I changed it, but I don't have enough points.  Maybe someone can tell me if what I did is the correct way to fix this issue or not.

---

Originally posted by [mrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30238/mrobot/) with karma: 16 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0